# How do I return Transaction and Campaign information on Confirmation Page?

Tags: php, cookies, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've been reading up on how to return transaction information once a user checks out and reaches the confirmation page. For example, I would like to receive the **time/date, order total, and product information** along with the **campaign** info, using the user's cookies possibly to see what campaigns are being used and which ones aren't.

So far, I've found a couple methods that are close to what I want to do. But between all the different documentation and deprecated methods, I'm a little overwhelmed.

I think the best way for me to go about this is just grab a custom variable from the URL or from the cookie once the user reaches the confirmation page.

Is this so? And how do I actually go about this? Please, if you link to Google documentation, can you explain it in a simpler way for me?

Comment: Do you want to see the information within the GA interface, or do you want to pass this to a script in realtime (the latter is not really possible, the current version of GA does not anymore store campaign info in the cookie).

Comment: I just want to be able to pull it. If there's a way I can grab that information and store it in a variable. I could even write it to a log or my own program, as long as I can pass that information to something. Is there anyway I can get the campaign information then?

Comment: Sorry for the double post but would I be able to use the Classic Analytics tracker then?